# Physics and math behind flight through solar system: Where to start?

Tags: gravity, space, simulations, space-travel

I wrote a first program that simulates a solar system. I was able to calculate the locations for every planet on its elliptical route for any given time.
In a second program i managed to simulate newtonian gravitational behavior (n-body problem, time-step approach).

But i'm wondering how it is possible to:
  (1) find routes (different possibilities) from a given location/planet to another
  (2) choose the best route according to duration or fuel cosumption

**So where's a good place to start?**

To be more exact: It's not about writing another simulation, its about understanding the physics behind it!

Until now, i was not able to find any good resources on the internet.

Comment: (not enough for a full answer but...) You should have a good understanding of energy (like the Oberth effect) and different types of transfer orbits. From there you can construct a decently efficient path piece-wise. (There are some good articles on this based around the popular video game "kerbal space program") And then there are the magical things I know little about: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Pz-3360uNoA/UTthQF-SdQI/AAAAAAAAdnM/yy4f5b6CkRc/w800-h800/photo.jpg and http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~jm/Choreographies/

Comment: A related question that you might find interesting: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26148/16660.

Comment: This looks like a good place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_spaceflight

Comment: joe, the first thing to know in real-life space flight is that planets' trajectories are not elliptical. The second and third stops on your way are Lambert's problem and patched conics. Fourth: what propulsion do you use? Fifth: there are loads of resources on the Net and in libraries...

Comment: And regarding point (2), you want to look into optimization theory for the math behind selecting the "best" of "something" given whatever criteria you provide.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't set up some kind of minimisation problem that could be solved numerically.

Comment: @DeerHunter: `planets' trajectories are not elliptical`: as you may read between the lines, that's clear to me. `Lambert's problem`: good hint!

Comment: @DanielBlay: Please be more exact...

Comment: @joe - unfortunately my vagueness is a result of ignorance rather than laziness. I had the principle of least action in mind; I don't see why you couldn't find some scalar potential that encompasses the necessary requirements and then use the calculus of variations to find a path along it such that the work required is minimised. This is probably a lot more abstract than what you're looking for.

EDIT: Actually I feel like this method may be in principle equivalent to huseyin tugrul buyukisik's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as calculating a lightwave's shortest path between points A and B where A is in air and B is in glass, you can put the actual functions of mediums then take the derivative. Just like the Snell's Law : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell's_law. (but this time, medium is not constant, there are moving masses that change space and time)

There wont be a medium constant but instead you put space/time indexes where it will change near planets and stars.

Maybe you can use finite-element-approach instead. Just use a spherical(3D) wave(or circular 2D) generating point in the finite element matrix then watch every piece of wavefront. Which wavefront point reaches your target first, will be the spaceship.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Actually a very interesting answer! Upvoted. Currently i have no idea how to model this in a piece of program. What's the math behind it?

Comment: Just some diffusion algorithm like any FEM, plus you already have the nbody thing right? Maybe a flux/velocity solver can be needed on top of the diffusion as "advect" solver. Any wave propagation algorithm should work.

Comment: Well, i'm not a physicist....

Comment: You like math? If so, you may look at Navier-Stokes equations and Poisson differential equations. This is even more embarrasingly-parallel than nbody algorithm so you can use gpu better.

Comment: If these are not your liking, then you can just release 3600 spaceships from point A (10 for each degree resolution) then just check if one arrives at B. You may do with 360000 to get a more precise shooting/starting angle.

Comment: All things above takes assumption of your spaceship just fires the engines all the time and does not try to change the angle, making the gravity do its job.

Comment: Im sure this is not used by anywhere by anyone, this is just not enough for important real missions. If you are good programmer, you can start a neural-network then train it to approach a target within a gravity field, then give your problem to it and it solves using its experience.

Comment: The best answer for me is solving like Snell's Law. Just with variable parameters. I mean like the derivation of Snell's Law.

Comment: You can start here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Optics/Fermat's_Principle

Comment: I'm impressed, let's see if i'm able to implement this. Completely great answer!

Comment: Work hard, have fun.

Comment: Totally right !

Comment: This method only applies for free motion. The spaceship, otoh has some finite resources (propellant) and it is possible to spend it in infinitely many ways (basically providing vector thrust $\vec{f}(t)$ as a function of time). So the problem is of finding extremal (least time or least propellant) solution over **functional space**.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at the **Interplanetary Transport Network** [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_Transport_Network) and [this article (pdf)](http://www2.esm.vt.edu/~sdross/papers/AmericanScientist2006.pdf). This is a way for interplanetary [travel using very little propellant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_energy_transfers).

The idea behind this is quite simple. It is well known that particles freely moving in the gravitational fields of several bodies exhibit chaotic motion, which means that nearby trajectories often exponentially diverge with time. So by using very little propellant the spacecraft can jump between such trajectories. The trick is to identify 'hubs' for such trajectories, like various Lagrange points, into which many trajectories to and from various destinations converge. Then the spacecraft using small 'nudges' jumps first onto path to such hub, then, once there, on a path to its next destination.